# Generate string with variable words in dynamic places in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random, replace

I saw Skype do this with their bots, their chat is randomized to make it look more human:

```
{Hi|Hey|Hello}, my name is a bot. {It's|It is} very {awesome|dope|cool} to meet you!
```

And the program replaces the {} parts with one random word from the ones specified, for example:

```
Hi, my name is a bot. It's very cool to meet you!
```

I was thinking about how this is possible, but other than putting every word into an array, running through all of them searching for "{" and "}" and after that replacing the string, I could not think about anything else.

You all are very creative and I'm sure there is another, better way of doing this.

Comment: Post some code. What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a "code this for me" site

Comment: I wrote about the code a little bit, but I will share it in a second.

Comment: Although I said the code can work, but it won't be very efficient. That's why I'm asking if anyone knows a better way of doing so.

Comment: Google for "templating javascript string".

Comment: I assume you're worried about efficiency because you are going to be running this code one billion times?

Comment: I think it is important to make your code as readable as possible, so it will be easier to modify it if needed later on. Also, this should help other users that want to achieve the same thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to accomplish your design:

```
let s = '{Hi|Hey|Hello}, my name is a bot. {It\'s|It is} very {awesome|dope|cool} to meet you!';
console.log(s.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/g, (a, v) => {
    let array = v.split('|');
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length))];
});
```

Comment: Yes! exactly what I was searching. I knew there is a better, cleaner way of doing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would want an array of possible words, and to choose one at random each time as such:

```
let greetings = ["Hi", "Hey", "Hello"];
let adjective = ["awesome", "dope", "cool"];
let phrase = `${greetings[Math.floor(Math.random()*greetings.length)]}, my name is a bot. It's very ${adjective[Math.floor(Math.random()*adjective.length)]} to meet you!`
```

This uses template literals.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes the string, searches for the beginning and end delimiters ("{" and "}"), then take that substring and split it on a pipe ("|").

Your function should splice the string and take only one of those words and put it back together for each set of {words|like|this}

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was going to do, I guess this is the only way haha

Answer (score 0):

Use **`str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)`**

Where:
**regexp** detect pattern `{}` then pass it to the **function**
**function** will do the replacement. split token by `|` and replace.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Yep just like tibetty suggested, it works! thank you as well

Answer (score 0):

```js
const random = a => a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];

const input = "{Hi|Hey|Hello}, my name is a bot. {It's|It is} very {awesome|dope|cool} to meet you!";

console.log(input.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, (_, v) => random(v.split('|'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "{Hi|Hey|Hello}, my name is a bot. {It's|It is} very  {awesome|dope|cool} to meet you";

str = str.replace(/{([^}]+)}/g, function(p, m){
  var arr = m.split("|");
  return arr[~~(Math.random() * arr.length)];
});

console.log( str ); // insert str into element.
```

Answer (score 0):

A library i worked on is suitable for doing such things, here is an example.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/suchjs/such@master/dist/such.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(){
  const globalSuch = Such.default;
  globalSuch.assign('hi', ['Hi', 'Hey', 'Hello']);
  globalSuch.assign('it', ['It\'s', 'It is']);
  globalSuch.assign('cool', ['awesome', 'dope', 'cool']);
  const tmpl = globalSuch.template('`:dict:#[data=hi]`, my name is a bot. `:dict:#[data=it]` very `:dict:#[data=cool]` to meet you!');
  console.log(tmpl.a());
  console.log(tmpl.a());
  console.log(tmpl.a());
  console.log(tmpl.a());
})();
</script>
```